"Failed to open /dev/cec0: Operation not permitted" when running an event script from raspotify.service
I'm running a freshly installed Raspberry Pi wuth Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm).
On it there is a raspotify service installed, which is running great and "mostly just works", as it says on the can.
I'd like to handle the service's events and issue CEC commands to the stereo (of course).
I've installed cec-utils and from command line this works well enough:
cec-ctl -s -t5 --cec-version-1.4  --user-control-pressed=ui-cmd=power-on-function

I.e. the amp powers up. But then I put this command into a /usr/bin/spotify-events.sh which looks like this:

#!/bin/bash
echo $PLAYER_EVENT;

if [ "$PLAYER_EVENT" = "start" ] || [ "$PLAYER_EVENT" = "session_connected" ] || [ "$PLAYER_EVENT" == "playing" ] ; then
  cec-ctl -s -t5 --cec-version-1.4  --user-control-pressed=ui-cmd=power-on-function
fi


and I hook it up to librespot's event via the /etc/raspotify/conf:
LIBRESPOT_ONEVENT="/usr/bin/spotify-events.sh"

After restarting the service, I can see that the scrips is hooked up, by the output in the log, but it also complains about opening /dev/cec0:
Dec 01 22:27:54 raspberrypi librespot[3584]: Failed to open /dev/cec0: Operation not permitted

The service runs as root, as far as I understand, doesn't it?

yuri@raspberrypi:/dev $ systemctl show -pUser,UID raspotify
UID=[not set]
User=

The /dev/cec0 is currently like this:
yuri@raspberrypi:/dev $ ls -l -a | grep cec0
crwxrwxrwx   1 root video 242,   0 Dec  1 15:41 cec0


because in desperation I chmodded it to 777 without it helping anything. I also tried
sudo usermod -a -G video root

as another desperate move.
So, I don't really get it, if the device is owned by root and group video, and the service is running as root, apparently, what other permissions do we need here? Or does the script not inherit the process' "user context" (I'm sorry, I'm not a Linux person, at all)
I suppose I can run whoami from the script, easily enough...
UPDATE: whoami in the script shows "root"
Any help is appreciated!

Sorry, it's "Operation not permitted", not "Permission denied". Editing the title.

After two evenings of trying to understand it, here's what I found. Apparently, the services have some sort of restriction on device use, so to fix the issue and to actually allow raspotify service to control the external device via CEC over HDMI, through cec-utils:
sudo nano cd /lib/systemd/system/raspotify.service
this would be some sort of "definition" of the service
Look for lines like:
DevicePolicy=strict 
DeviceAllow=char-alsa rw 
... 
(there'd be a bunch of those) 

Put in:
DeviceAllow=/dev/cec0 rw
Make it all restart, f.ex.
systemctl restart raspotify
systemctl daemon-reload
(Quite possible it is enough with just the last one)
Now the service is permitted to use the device for reading and writing and the script works. In my case it turns the appliance on so far, I'll have to put back some lines to switch to the source that we are plugged into.
